# Как передать массив структур по сети?

Tags: c++builder, c++, сокет, клиент-сервер

Есть структура следующего содержание:

```
struct Ships{
    int shL;
    int shT;
    int shW;
    int shH;
    int shDL;
    int shDT;
    int size;
    bool vertical;
    int *shInner;
    int *shOuter;
    int shInnerSize;
    int shOuterSize;
    TImage **blue;
    TImage **red;
    int shHealth;
    bool init;
};
```

Объявление для клиента:

```
struct Ships iShip[10];
```

Объявление для сервера:

```
struct Ships iTemp[10];
```

Для передачи пробовал использовать компоненты клиент\серверсокет.

Выглядит это так:

На клиенте:

```
ClientSocket1->Socket->SendBuf(&iShip,sizeof(iShip));
```

На сервере:

```
ServerSocket1->Socket->SendBuf(&iTemp,sizeof(iTemp));
```

Передача прошла без ошибок, и я мог считывать те переменные, что не были созданы динамически (shL,shT и т.д.), а вот данные из массивов shInner и shOuter уже нет, вылезает ошибка связанная с адресацией. Как я понял, я передаю только адреса начала этих массивов, но не данные. Так вот вопрос как передать еще и данные в них?

Comment: написать сериализацию или вручную прописывать передачу. Та же картинка умеет сохранятся в stream. Достаточно легко заставить ее сохранять в сокет.

Comment: Передача картинки то не так важна, главное мне передать эти массивы.

Comment: Хм. Вы понимаете, что вы делаете? Вы передаёте указатель по сети и надеетесь, что на той стороне это всё ещё будет валидный указатель, и по нему магическим образом возникнут нужные данные?

Answer (score 1):

Сохраните структуру в [Json](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) строку и передавайте на здоровье.

Для плюсов есть либы для работы с Json - погугли и найдешь.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, Json тут прикручивать, издеваетесь?

Это же *морской бой*. Там максимальный размер этих "динакмических" массивов пара десятков байт.

Положить (сразу) их в структуру и гонять на здлолвье.

Comment: А откуда я знаю что это морской бой?!

Answer (score 0):

если кол-во данных в массивах известно заранее - можно просто объявить как массив - и все взлетит. То-есть например для массивов из 10 элементов:

```
struct Ships{
    int shL;
    int shT;
    int shW;
    int shH;
    int shDL;
    int shDT;
    int size;
    bool vertical;
    int[10] shInner;
    int[10] shOuter;
    int shInnerSize;
    int shOuterSize;
    TImage **blue;
    TImage **red;
    int shHealth;
    bool init;
};
```

Но в общем случае - нужен серилизатор - protobuf, json, xml - кто угодно. Для такого рода данных protocol buffer будет самое оно.